# How do you make use of multiple templates when you are loading a page using Django?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Suppose the layout of the pages that I want to load are of the form:

a)

```
<p>Hello</p>    -- varies
<h1>World</h1>    -- fixed
<h6>foo</h6>      -- varies
```

b)

```
<h2>Hey</h2>
<h1>World</h1>
<h2>bar</h2>
```

and so on, where some part of the page is common to all the pages (say, the part with the banner, search box etc.) but the layout of other parts are different.

Is there a way to combine multiple templates without having to copy-paste the common parts to each file?

PS: Using Django1.7 and Python 3.4 on a Win8 PC.

Comment: You really, really need to read: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/templates/

Comment: Django's [template language](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/templates/) (specifically [`extends`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/templates/#template-inheritance)) provides this functionality. You need to read the documentation then post a specific question.

Comment: Sorry, I'm really really new to Django. Just went through the tutorial and started trying out something!

Answer (score 3):

you can use 2 solutions:

1-use `extends`:

define `base.html` template like this:

```
<p>{% block var1 %}{% endblock %}</p>    -- varies
<h1>World</h1>    -- fixed
<h6>{% block var2 %}{% endblock %}</h6>      -- varies
```

and use `base.html` like this:

`a)`:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block var1 %}Hello{% endblock %}
{% block var2 %}foo{% endblock %}
```

`b)`:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block var1 %}Hey{% endblock %}
{% block var2 %}bar{% endblock %}
```

2- use `include`:

define `fix.html`:

```
<h1>World</h1>
```

and use it like this:

`a):`

```
<p>Hello</p>    -- varies
{% include "fix.html" %}
<h6>foo</h6>      -- varies
```

`b):`

```
<p>Hey</p>    -- varies
{% include "fix.html" %}
<h6>bar</h6>      -- varies
```

Comment: This is pretty much what you need...make sure you read the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/templates/

Comment: Where should I place the file "base.html"? I keep getting an error saying that it does not exist and I've tried placing it in quite a few folders!